# R twitteR package maxID doesn't work on Mavericks

Tags: r, twitter, rcurl, httr

I am trying to crawl tweets with twitteR package version twitteR_1.1.8  and I want to do this operation by using maxID. Even maxID property is in the twitteR manual which is published on February,11; I get a warning that maxID is unrecognized. Let me explain myself with an example:

```
> t <- searchTwitter('#sample',n=10)
> sapply(t,function(x) x$getId())

 [1] "567760958798700545" "567760485538615296" "567760474096168961"
 [4] "567759761916325888" "567757164480299009" "567752193219235840"
 [7] "567751648655982594" "567750943216001024" "567747456667254784"
 [10] "567745734087172096"
> t1 <- searchTwitter('#sample',n=5,maxID='567757164480299009')

Warning messages:
1: In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: maxid
2: In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: maxid
> sapply(t1,function(x) x$getId())
[1] "567760958798700545" "567760485538615296" "567760474096168961"
[4] "567759761916325888" "567757164480299009"
```

As you see I cannot simply use maxID in the code. R version 3.1.2 and twitteR version twitteR_1.1.8.  What can the problem be? Thanks in advance..

Comment: What version of the twitteR package do you have installed? Check with `sessionInfo()` which version is loaded.

Comment: I am currently using twitteR_1.1.8

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me using `twitteR` 1.1.8.  The error you're getting isn't coming from `twitteR`, its coming from the `RCurl` package.  That package has gone through a few revisions recently, one of which, on my system, caused any `https://` request to fail.  So, I think that's your primary suspect.  Another potential suspect is the `httr` package.

For reference, I'm using `RCurl_1.95-4.5` and `httr_0.6.1`.

Comment: Actually my offıce computer works fıne too. I am exactly using the same versions as yours. I updated, removed and installed the packages again and again but this didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Then check the version of curl that is installed on each machine.  RCurl links against curl.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem - in spite of having the max(id) as the sinceID I am getting repeated tweets!

This is the code:

```
my_tweets = searchTwitter(as.character(v_search[,i]), lang=NULL, n=10, sinceID = arr_since_id[i])
    v_max_id <- max(my_tweets$id)
    arr_since_id[i] <- v_max_id
```

> packageVersion("RCurl")
>   [1] ‘1.95.4.5’
>
> packageVersion("twitteR")
>   [1] ‘1.1.8’
>
> packageVersion("httr")
>   [1] ‘0.6.1’